# Bluemix node.js app deployment fails when using Q node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ibm-cloud, q

I am using `Bluemix` to deploy a sample `node.js` app. Everything works fine if i don't require `Q` package inside my app code. But the app deployment fails if i require the `Q` package inside my code.

Here's my app code -

```
/*eslint-env node*/
var express = require('express'),
    cfenv = require('cfenv'),
    //bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    //multer = require('multer'),
    Q = require('Q');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});
app.listen(appEnv.port, '0.0.0.0', function() {
  console.log("server starting on " + appEnv.url);
});
```

However, when i check the logs `Q` module is indeed installed and shows as below.

```
├── q@1.4.1
```

Bluemix deployment logs -

```
2016-05-03T00:30:05.46+0530 [App/0]      ERR module.js:328
2016-05-03T00:30:05.46+0530 [App/0]      ERR     throw err;
2016-05-03T00:30:05.46+0530 [App/0]      ERR     ^
2016-05-03T00:30:05.46+0530 [App/0]      ERR Error: Cannot find module 'Q'
2016-05-03T00:30:05.46+0530 [App/0]      ERR     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
2016-05-03T00:30:05.46+0530 [App/0]      ERR     at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
2016-05-03T00:30:05.46+0530 [App/0]      ERR     at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
2016-05-03T00:30:05.46+0530 [App/0]      ERR     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
2016-05-03T00:30:05.46+0530 [App/0]      ERR     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/app.js:6:9)
2016-05-03T00:30:05.46+0530 [App/0]      ERR     at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
2016-05-03T00:30:05.46+0530 [App/0]      ERR     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
2016-05-03T00:30:05.46+0530 [App/0]      ERR     at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
2016-05-03T00:30:05.46+0530 [App/0]      ERR     at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
2016-05-03T00:30:05.46+0530 [App/0]      ERR     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
2016-05-03T00:30:05.48+0530 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-25-generic
2016-05-03T00:30:05.48+0530 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! argv "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-05-03T00:30:05.48+0530 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! node v4.2.6
2016-05-03T00:30:05.48+0530 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
2016-05-03T00:30:05.48+0530 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-05-03T00:30:05.48+0530 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! SampleNodeApp@0.0.1 start: `node app.js`
2016-05-03T00:30:05.48+0530 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Exit status 1
2016-05-03T00:30:05.48+0530 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! 
2016-05-03T00:30:05.48+0530 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Failed at the SampleNodeApp@0.0.1 start script 'node app.js'.
2016-05-03T00:30:05.48+0530 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the SampleNodeApp package,
2016-05-03T00:30:05.48+0530 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-05-03T00:30:05.48+0530 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-05-03T00:30:05.48+0530 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR!     node app.js
2016-05-03T00:30:05.48+0530 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! You can get their info via:
2016-05-03T00:30:05.48+0530 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR!     npm owner ls SampleNodeApp
2016-05-03T00:30:05.48+0530 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-05-03T00:30:05.49+0530 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-05-03T00:30:05.49+0530 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR!     /home/vcap/app/npm-debug.log
2016-05-03T00:30:05.56+0530 [DEA/137]    ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
```

**NOTE:** If i remove the line `Q = require('Q')` everything works fine and app gets deployed and started successfully. Also i have tested it locally on my machine and it works perfectly fine.

Any suggestions or solutions? Thanks!

Comment: how is this working locally when you're requiring `Q` instead of `q`?

Comment: @seth well, it somehow works locally in my machine and doesn't throw any error about node module not being found. That is really strange. I don't understand why it doesn't throw that error locally. And interesting thing is it works in both cases small or caps `q`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
var Q = require('q');
```

The q module name is `q`, not `Q`.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me with the casing. Got to know that osx and windows are not case sensitive and so it doesn't throw any error, but it does on linux based env.

Answer (score 1):

The key to your problem is this error:

`Error: Cannot find module 'Q'`

The name of the module is not `Q`, it is `q`. Change that value and it will fix your issue.